# BPM or rake-pipeline-web-filters with Ember.js, Which one is recommended?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to setup a development environment for Ember.js that allows me to load js classess and handlebar templates from separate files (the way SC used to do it). Which is the recommended way to go?  BPM or rake-pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core team is using rake-pipeline for active projects but I'm told they do have plans to continue active development of BPM and are not abandoning it. Many people still use BPM for active projects.

Currently you can use BPM with Ember without any problems. I personally have taken interest in BPM and will keep [www.getbpm.org](http://www.getbpm.org) is up-to-date with new releases of Ember until the core team gets to the point of actively maintaining it again. So right now BPM is community supported.

Comment: So, in the future, is the core team more likely to use BPM or rake-pipeline or both?

Comment: To my knowledge, they will support and actively develop both.

Comment: Hey, sorry to keep bouncing back with questions. I've been playing with rake-pipeline but I haven't been able to set-up a devel-time proxy for ajax calls to a server. Is this functionality built into BPM? Or is BPM "just" a package manager?  (related question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810118/proxy-for-ajax-calls-using-rake-pipeline-web-filters)

Comment: Happy to help where I can man! BPM is just a package manager. I just set up my own proxy on my dev machine. I'm not sure what else other developers do. That might be a good question to ask on the #emberjs IRC channel on freenode.

Answer (score 2):

**Both rake-pipeline and BPM are deprecated and no longer maintained.**

Continuing efforts are focused on a combination of [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli), [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit), and the related [ember-appkit-rails](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-appkit-rails). We're also excited about the development of [Broccoli](http://www.solitr.com/blog/2014/02/broccoli-first-release/). The long term plan, as I understand it, is to have ember-cli serve as a front to either EAK or Broccoli.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, rake-pipeline, Bpm is not yet being supported.

Look at the AssetFile on the emberjs projects to see how must be configured using rake-pipeline and rake-pipeline-web-filters.