# Proxy for ajax calls using rake-pipeline-web-filters

Tags: rake-pipeline

I'm setting up my devel environment for an Ember.js app using rake-pipeline as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8558062/setting-up-rake-pipeline-for-use-with-handlebars-alongside-google-app-engine).

During development, my html and javascript are served by webrick (rake-filter magic that I don't quite understand) on `http://0.0.0.0:9292` and I have a REST service developed in php served by Apache on `http://somename.local`

My ajax calls from the client app are getting lost because of the browser's anti-cross-domain-ajax thing. How do I work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure the proxy directly in your Assetfile. You'll have to create a `config.ru` file and use the `rackup` command to launch the server.

Here's an example Assetfile:

```
input "app"
output "public"
```

And config.ru:

```
require 'rake-pipeline'
require 'rake-pipeline/middleware'
require "rack/streaming_proxy" # Don't forget to install the rack-streaming-proxy gem.

use Rack::StreamingProxy do |request|
  # Insert your own logic here
  if request.path.start_with?("/api")
    "http://localhost#{request.path.sub("/api", "")}"
  end
end

use Rake::Pipeline::Middleware, 'Assetfile' # This is the path to your Assetfile
run Rack::Directory.new('public') # This should match whatever your Assetfile's output directory is
```

You'll have to install the rack and rack-streaming-proxy gems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rack::Proxy](http://coderack.org/users/cwninja/middlewares/18-rackproxy) and then just send the needed requests to the proxy.

```
  if request.path.start_with?("/api")
    URI.parse("http://localhost:80#{request.path}")
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, could you elaborate a bit more? I have an Assetfile that looks like this https://gist.github.com/1608930  Where would I add the Rack::Proxy code?

Comment: And how does this transfer the method, POST, DELETE, or PUT? It looks like you're just converting every method into a GET.